# Hard indefinite integral (relating to probability)

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I want to show that $$\frac{1-t}{2\pi} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}}{s+tx}dx = \frac{1}{1-t},$$ where $a = \frac{(1-h)^2}{(1-t)^2}, b = \frac{(1+h)^2}{(1-t)^2}$ and $h = \sqrt{s+t-st}$.

I have tried the following so far: Let us manipulate the integrand into something reasonable to deal with. To this end, we have \begin{eqnarray*}
a+b &=& \frac{(1-h)^2}{(1-t)^2} + \frac{(1+h)^2}{(1-t)^2} = \frac{1-2h+h^2 + 1 + 2h + h^2}{(1-t)^2} = 2\frac{h^2+1}{(1-t)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*} Similarly, we have \begin{eqnarray*}
ab &=& \frac{(1-h)^2(1+h)^2}{(1-t)^4} = \frac{(1-h^2)^2}{(1-t)^4}.
\end{eqnarray*} Thus, \begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)} &=& \sqrt{(a+b)x - ab - x^2} \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2x(h^2+1)}{(1-t)^2}  - \frac{(1-h^2)^2}{(1-t)^4} - x^2} \\
&=&\sqrt{- \left( \left( x - \frac{(h^2+1)}{(1-t)^2} \right)^2 - \frac{(h^2+1)^2 + (1-h^2)^2}{(1-t)^4}  \right)} \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2h^4 + 2}{(1-t)^4} - \left( x - \frac{(h^4+1)}{(1-t)^2} \right)^2} \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{2h^4 + 2}{(1-t)^4} - \left( \frac{(1-t)^2 x - (h^4+1)}{(1-t)^2} \right)^2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \sqrt{2h^4 + 2 - [(1-t)^2 x - (h^4+1) ]^2 }. 
\end{eqnarray*} So we currently have \begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}}{s+tx}dx &=& \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \int  \frac{\sqrt{2h^4 + 2 - [(1-t)^2 x - (h^4 + 1)]^2}}{s+tx}dx 
\end{eqnarray*} Now let us attempt to make the substitution $$u = 2h^4 + 2 - [(1-t)^2 x - (h^4 + 1)]^2.$$ From this, we see that \begin{eqnarray*}
du = -2(1-t)^2[(1-t)^2 x - (h^4+1)] dx,
\end{eqnarray*} and \begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& \frac{-(h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4 + 1) - u}}{2(1-t)^2}. 
\end{eqnarray*} Inserting this into our expression for the integral, we have \begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \int  \frac{\sqrt{2h^4 + 2 - [(1-t)^2 x - (h^4 + 1)]^2}}{s+tx}dx  \\
&=& \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{s+t \left( \frac{-(h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4 + 1) - u}}{2(1-t)^2} \right) } \frac{du}{-2(1-t)^2[(1-t)^2 \left( \frac{-(h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4 + 1) - u}}{2(1-t)^2} \right) - (h^4+1)]} \\
&=& \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{s+t \left( (h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4+1)-u} \right)[(1-t)^2 \left( \frac{-(h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4 + 1) - u}}{2(1-t)^2} \right) - (h^4+1)]}du \\
&=& \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{s+ t \left( (h^4+1) \pm \sqrt{2(h^4+1) -u} \right) [- \frac{1}{2}(h^4+1) \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2(h^4+1) -u} - (h^4+1) ] }
\end{eqnarray*}

There must be a quicker way to solve this...

Comment: Are there limits on this integral?

Comment: @Chappers Sorry, yes, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. It is a calculation of the first moment of a probability distribution.

Comment: Are you sure? The square root's only real for $a \leq x \leq b$.

Comment: @Chappers The question is poorly expressed, I think it must be between $a \leq x \leq b$ then.

Comment: @Chappers I have made the appropriate edits

Comment: @MyGlasses From what I've been given, they are treated as independent variables

Comment: @MyGlasses Is there a solution online?

Comment: @MyGlasses You said you found the solution?

Comment: @YinPeiTo. Done! I stucked in  a minus for several hours.

Answer (score 2):

With substitution $x=b+(a-b)u$ 
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}}{s+tx}dx 
&=
-\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(b-a)\sqrt{u(1-u)}}{ \frac{(h+t)^2}{(1-t)^2} \left(1-\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}u\right)}(a-b)du
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{u(1-u)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}u\right)^n\,du
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}\right)^n\int_{0}^{1}u^{\frac12+n}(1-u)^{\frac12}\,du
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}\right)^n\beta(\dfrac32+n,\frac32)
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}\right)^n\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac32+n)}{\Gamma(n+3)}\dfrac12\sqrt{\pi}
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\dfrac12\sqrt{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}\right)^n \dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac32+n)}{\Gamma(n+3)}
\\
&=
\dfrac{(1-t)^2}{(h+t)^2}(a-b)^2\dfrac12\sqrt{\pi} \dfrac{(h+t)^2}{4h^2}\sqrt{\pi}
\\
&=
\color{blue}{\dfrac{2\pi}{(1-t)^2}}
\end{align}
where $\beta(x,y)$ is [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Could you please explain the second last equality simplifying the last series?

Comment: With $\dfrac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}=\alpha$ then with $n=r-2$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac32+n)}{\Gamma(n+3)}\alpha^n
&=\dfrac{\Gamma(-\dfrac12)}{\alpha^2}\sum_{r=2}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma(r-\dfrac12)}{\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(-\dfrac12)}\alpha^n \\
&=\dfrac{\Gamma(-\dfrac12)}{\alpha^2}\left((1-\alpha)^\frac12-\alpha^0-\dfrac12\alpha^1\right)\\
\end{align}
simplify with $\Gamma(-\dfrac12)=-2\sqrt{\pi}$ and then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac32+n)}{\Gamma(n+3)}\left(\frac{4ht}{(h+t)^2}\right)^n=\dfrac{(h+t)^2}{4h^2}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you. I did realize later that it was just the binomial expansion before coming back here, seeing that was exactly what you have written out here. +1

Answer (score 2):

One can avoid power series as follows: as in @MyGlasses's answer, put $u=a+(b-a)x$ to get
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{(b-a)^2\sqrt{u(1-u)}}{s+at+(b-a)tu} \, du $$
Now set $u=\sin^2{(\theta/2)}$, and the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(b-a)^2 \sin{(\theta/2)}\cos{(\theta/2)} \cdot \sin{(\theta/2)}\cos{(\theta/2)}}{s+at+(b-a)t\sin^2{(\theta/2)}} \, d\theta \\
= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{4} \frac{(b-a)^2 \sin^2{\theta}}{s+at+(b-a)t(1-\cos{\theta})/2} \, d\theta \\
= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(b-a)^2 \sin^2{\theta}}{(4s+2(a+b)t)-2(b-a)t\cos{\theta}} \, d\theta $$

Now, $b-a = \frac{4h}{(1-t)^2}$, and
$$ 4s+2(a+b)t = \frac{4(1-t)^2s+4(1+h^2)t}{(1-t)^2} = 4\frac{s-2st+st^2+t+st+t^2-st^2}{(1-t)^2} = 4\frac{h^2+t^2}{(1-t)^2} $$
Cancelling gives
$$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(b-a)^2 \sin^2{\theta}}{(4s+2(a+b)t)-2(b-a)t\cos{\theta}} \, d\theta = \frac{4}{(1-t)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{h^2\sin^2{\theta}}{h^2+t^2-2ht\cos{\theta}} \, d\theta. $$
This integral's value changes depending on which of $h$ and $t$ is bigger. One can compute it using residues, the Fourier expansion of the denominator, or $t=\tan{(\theta/2)}$, and we find it is
$$ \frac{4}{(1-t)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{h^2\sin^2{\theta}}{h^2+t^2-2ht\cos{\theta}} \, d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{(1-t)^2} \begin{cases} 1 & h^2 \geq t^2 \\ h^2/t^2 & h^2<t^2 \end{cases}. $$

Comment: That is what I would have done. +1